# Error on Composer while deploying Laravel project to Gcloud App engine

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, gcloud

I have developed a Laravel App simple `CRUD` operations. While deployed on Gcloud. The logs shows on terminal are:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeiMP.png)

in this it shows error on

> Step #1: Install PHP extensions...
>   Step #1: Running composer...
>   Step #1: Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Step #1: Installing dependencies from lock file
>   Step #1: Package operations: 41 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
>   Step #1: As there is no 'unzip' command installed zip files are being unpacked using the PHP zip extension.
>   Step #1: This may cause invalid reports of corrupted archives. Installing 'unzip' may remediate them.
>   ...

Please help me regards this

Thank you

Comment: it clearly says that you should install `unzip` on the machine where you ran that command

Comment: I have installed unzip on my local machine. May i need to do something on gcloud server

Comment: on which machine are you executing `composer install`?

Comment: I have project on my local machine when I run `gcloud app deploy` then in its log it show error from this line mentions above.

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with the [latest Google Cloud SDK version](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes) ?

Make sure you do, update your current version like so:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

Are you sure you have the correct unzip tool installed? [This is the one](https://www.luminanetworks.com/docs-lsc-610/Topics/SDN_Controller_Software_Installation_Guide/Appendix/Installing_Zip_and_Unzip_for_Ubuntu_1.html).